# Como obter corretamente o conteúdo de uma imagem utilizando o fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Utilizando a função `fetch` eu preciso obter o conteúdo de uma imagem obtida na resposta do servidor. O problema é que essa imagem está vindo com o conteúdo diferente do que deveria.

**Utilizando "requests" no Python:**

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xed\x00 ...
```

**Utilizando "fetch" no JavaScript:**

```
���� JFIF �� |Photoshop 3.0 8BIM...
```

Preciso que o conteúdo obtido no `fetch` seja o mesmo que o obtido no `requests` do Python, para que a imagem seja salva depois no computador. Abaixo está o meu código:

```js
async function get_image_data_from(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    return await response.text();
}
```

Comment: A imagem é dado binário, você tem o buscar como [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) `response.blob();` . Se buscar como texto vai o corromper. Dá uma olhada nesse [exemplo](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/RarePrettyBoastmachine#index.js)

Comment: @AugustoVasques estou procurando por uma solução que não seja necessário instalar mais um pacote porque eu já estou utilizando um pacote chamado `puppeteer` que possui um método que executa um código JavaScript no navegador e retornar um valor. No caso eu preciso obter o conteúdo da imagem como se eu não estivesse utilizando Node.js e sim apenas JS puro do browser. É possível fazer isso ? O Luiz também tinha recomendado utilizar o método `blob` do `fetch` do browser na resposta (ele apagou a resposta), mas como eu disse, eu preciso obter o conteúdo em string para salvar a imagem.

Comment: Basicamente o método do pacote `puppeteer` (similar ao selenium) vai retornar um valor que será um código JS executado no próprio navegador sem Node. Após isso eu salvo este arquivo utilizando o `fs` com o retorno (conteúdo da imagem) do método. Se não for possível obter o conteúdo sem estar "bugado" através do `fetch` padrão, eu vou tentar este `node-fetch` mesmo.

Comment: No seu código de exemplo JS já está usando `fetch`, o título da pergunta é sobre fetch. No exemplo python aquele b na frente da string significa binário e se comparar os valores que tem em python com o exemplo que dei em js vai ver que o cabeçalho é o mesmo só não tem as barras `\`

Comment: No caso o pacote que usei é só um emulador do fetch do navegador para node.

Comment: Mas quando eu utilizo o método `blob` do `fetch` do browser eu não recebo o objeto como este do `node-fetch`.

Comment: Ai eu não sei como é comportamento do fetch síncrono. Mas tente criar uma imagem como blob `let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
 img.src = objectURL;`

Comment: Mas como posso obter esse buffer do objeto `Blob` para salvar em um arquivo com o pacote `fs` ?

Comment: Se é para gravar um arquivo use [`arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer) ao invés de blob() e salve como binário.

Comment: @AugustoVasques para não ficar muito longo aí, você pode me tirar uma dúvida que não é mais sobre o tema dessa pergunta lá no chat ?

Comment: Estou indo almoçar, estou em outro fuso horário. Mas sim quando voltar lhe auxilio.

Comment: Ta então, já vou deixar a pergunta lá no chat. Vlw e bom almoço :D

Comment: Se é uma imagem, não faz sentido converter para texto (por isso aparece esse monte de `?`). Enfim, pq não tenta salvar direto? Já tentou [alguma dessas soluções](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11944932)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function get_image_data_from( url ) {

let blob = await ( await fetch( url ) ).blob() 
// await ( await fetch( url ) ).text() a codificação será sempre utf-8.

let Response_BinaryStrings = await new Promise( (resolve) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve( reader.result );
    
    // texto para dados binários ==>
    reader.readAsBinaryString( blob ); // ==> codificação tipo Windows-1252.
    // ou ==> reader.readAsText( blob, 'x-user-defined' );
    } 
);

return Response_BinaryStrings;
}
```